# C++ - Sended request is not reaching other computer

Tags: c++, node.js, networking

I am using libcurl with C++ to send an HTTP request to another host (my friend's computer) over the Internet. Now, the other end uses a Node.js script to receive and handle the request.
I have tried the code (both C++ and Node) on my local network between my computers, and everything works just fine. This is the code, in case you wanna look at it:

```
CURL *handle;
string response;

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_WIN32);
handle = curl_easy_init();

curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, "10.10.10.10:7890"); //<= IP:PORT of the remote host
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "This is my POST request data!!");
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_to_string);
curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);

curl_easy_perform(handle);

curl_easy_cleanup(handle);
```

and the Node.js code:

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    request.on('data', function(chunk) {

        console.log("We got a connection!");

        console.log("Received POST data:");
        console.log(chunk.toString());

    });

});

server.listen(7890);
console.log("Server is listening");
```

As I said, on my local network it works very well, but why it doesn't my friend receive the request? I noticed that my code (C++ part) takes some time, before closing, as if it was trying to connect. Is this some kind of firewall problem? We have tried disabling it, but nothing changed. We are almost total noobs with networking, and we're trying to get into it.

If anybody could help us, thanks in advance!

Comment: '192.168.X.X' is not routeable.  It's a LAN address only.

Comment: Yeah, I changed that in the example, but we are using the connection IP, of course. I'll change that now

Comment: I see no error handling. How could you know what went wrong...

Comment: '10.10.10.10', really?  I guess you don't want to publish the real IP here:)

Comment: I know it's a local IP, but what should I use then? It's an example.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend's home router needs to know what to do with a connection being requested on port 7890 from the internet. It needs to be configured to forward any communication on that port to the specific internal IP address of your friend's computer.

Not all home routers are capable of port forwarding and many manufacturers have different ways of getting to the settings.

Any software firewall on the friend's computer also needs to know that communication over port 7890 is safe.